# How to install Recoll's python:epub helper?

Tags: python, epub, recoll

I installed the latest version of Recoll from the ppa because it was claimed it can index epub files.

When I select "Show missing helpers" there's "python:epub" in the list. I cannot find it in the software center. I already have the python-recoll package installed.

Answer (score 5):

As per a comment at [launchpad.net bugs site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1200717) , you can use the following workaround to get the python epub module installed:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip
 sudo pip install epub`

Comment: Cool!  Also works for another recoll-required python package not available for 14.04 via apt-get, namely rarfile.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Python epub module from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/epub/0.5.0

More generally the hopefully up-to-date information about Recoll helpers is here: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/features.html

This is in turn is pointed to from the manual: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html#RCL.INSTALL.EXTERNAL